# HOw to Fix 'Sql Trigger for Insert not working with Declare Variable'

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to insert rows from one table into another using a trigger with declared variable. When I run the code separately, it works for insert, but I want to create a trigger and return 0 rows

This is what I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER Final 
ON schedule
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Datatable (Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue,d) 
                    SELECT Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue, [' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DAY(GETDATE())) + '] AS d 
                    FROM schedule'

    EXEC (@sql) 
END
```

I expect the rows must be inserted into another table, but 0 rows are getting inserted

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: i m using dynamic sql to return column as variable name . [' + 
convert(nvarchar(max),day(getdate())) + '] as d

Comment: You have column names like `[1], [2], [3]` etc corresponding to the day of the month? This smells like a database design issue, more than anything else.

Comment: Based on your dynamic SQL, i don't see any reason for it. Even with your comment of `i m using dynamic sql to return column as variable name ` Can you elaborate?\

Comment: any reason for using triggers in the first place rather than just another insert into the table "Datatable" after you insert into "schedule" table?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `schedule` is empty.  You don't want to insert the rows from `schedule`.  You want to use `inserted` instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Final ON schedule
FOR INSERT
AS
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max); 
    set @sql = N'
insert into Datatable(Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs,Queue,d) 
    select Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue, [@d]
    from inserted
';
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@d', day(getdate());

    exec sp_executesql @sql;
end;

go
```

Having written this, I'm not sure if `inserted` is allowed in dynamic SQL.

Comment: i m using dynamic sql to return column as variable name. to return this column value --> [' + convert(nvarchar(max),day(getdate())) + '] as d

Comment: hi Gordon Linoff : you are almost there buddy, because if i use this declare @sql nvarchar(max); 
    set @ sql = N'
 insert into Datatable(Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs,Queue,d) 
    select Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue, [' + convert(nvarchar(max),day(getdate())) + '] as d
    from  schedule';
    exec (@ sql);     i m getting desire output, all i want to create trigger for the above query

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to use dynamic query, when you can just do it as below?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Final 
ON schedule
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Datatable (Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue,d) 
    SELECT Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),DAY(GETDATE()))
    FROM inserted

END
```

**UPDATE**

just by executing this part

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'SELECT [' + convert(nvarchar(max),day(getdate())) + '] AS d '

    print @sql

    EXEC (@sql)
```

you will see that your script is throwing an error as [9] (if we consider todays date) is invalid column, sql engine thinks its a column from your table schedule, get rid of the brackets and it should work fine

Comment: HI @Karthik Ganesan still no luck i tried this....declare @ sql nvarchar(max); 
    set @ sql = N'
 insert into Datatable(Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs,Queue,d) 
    select Name, SAP_ID, Enterprise_IDs, Queue, [' + convert(nvarchar(max),day(getdate())) + '] as d
    from  schedule';
    exec (@ sql);  and i m getting desired output...all i want to know how i can call this query using trigger

Comment: do a print on the generated @sql you will see you are basically doing a [day] while executing the dynamic sql, which makes sql engine think its a column and is throwing an error.. get rid of the square bracket and it should work fine